# When playing a TV in iTunes via AirPlay to Apple TV, it doesn't play the next episode

Tags: itunes, appletv, airplay

I have some TV shows in iTunes that I am AirPlaying to my Apple TV, at the end of each episode AirPlay disconnects and iTunes doesn't play the next episode. Is this default behaviour or do I need to make sure that the names/meta data of the TV shows themselves 'flow'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default (and only) behavior.  Whether you play the TV show from the special TV Show section of iTunes or create a playlist, iTunes will only play on TV show and then stop.  Try the playlist approach - iTunes won't even *play* the playlist, but forces you to select one show and then start playing.

Comment: Thank you, back to VLC and AirPlay mirroring, would just be nice to not have to share the 'whole' mac.

Comment: I've used VLC and AirPlay for non-iTunes content.  Off-topic, but is there a good way to remotely control the VLC playback?  Useful if the Mac is in another room from the ATV!

Comment: I believe that VLC remote is on the App Store. I've never used it as I'm always using my mac at the same time